# difference between global styles.scss and adding styles.scss to a component in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

Is there a difference between putting styles/mixins in styles.scss and adding them with `@use` or `@import` to a some-component.scss? (And removing `styles.scss` from `angular.json` styles section.) In case of @angular/material why does the first approach work and the second doesn't?

Comment: if you put a css in a component the scope it's only for this component ( * ), if you use styles.scss the scope style is the whole application. ( * ) you can change this behaivor using ViewState.None. Some components in material use cdk-overlay to show a pop-up. This create a div "outside" of the component, so you can not "reach" the css using .css with scope only in the component

Comment: Thanks, what you said makes perfect sense, I didn't think about elements created outside the component. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: don't worry about put an answer. An e.g. about "cdk-overlay-container". Create an app with a mat-dialog, if you open the dialog, see the "html" (using F12) you will see a `<cdk-overlay-container>` that is "outside" the component

Comment: Yes I saw that now. Thanks